# When replying to @username posts from transcript doesn't get oneboxed

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

When linking a message from the chat transcript or a comment it doesn't always onebox it.

When you type @username {link to message / comment} it is displayed as a link, but when clicking on reply in chat and add a link it does onebox, e.g.: :messageid {link to message / comment}.

[image]

Is it possible to also let the @mention messages onebox?

Comment: I think this is technically correct, since the prerequisite for one-boxing is that the link is the only thing on the message. Not sure it's worth special-casing this for @replies, but that's a question for Balpha. :)

Comment: Doesn't the arrow still work? That's how it shows up in chat too